# A timestamp conflict occurred on Stored Procedure DB2

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2, procedure

When I execute a stored procedure in DB2, it works ok, but after a little time it doesn´t work anymore, and I have to create again , without any changes, and this happens over and over again, the error is:

> SQL Error [51003]: A timestamp conflict occurred.. SQLCODE=-818, SQLSTATE=51003, DRIVER=4.16.53

Comment: What DB2 version and platform? What kind of application calls this stored procedure?

Comment: I use db2 9.7 and I executing the stored procedure directly on the database (command line)

Comment: Is this an SQL stored procedure or external? Does the system time on the database server change? How is the time on the server synchronized?